# \includegraphics produces ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Tags: errors, compiling

I have MacTeX-2023 with all packages updated (using Tex Live) on two computers running on macOS Monterey. I use TeXShop (version 5.12) on both computers. I am unable to compile on one of the computers whenever I include a figure in the document (see example below). Compilation (of the same document) works perfectly (with the same figure) on the second computer. Could anyone please advise me on what could be the problem?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
This is a test.

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{TestFig.pdf}

\end{document}
```

The TestFig.pdf file is located in the same folder.

If I comment out the `\includegraphics` command from the code, I can produce a .pdf file, but not otherwise.

Here is the .log file from the failed compilation:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.4.5)  5 APR 2023 11:54
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Test.tex
(./Test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-03-30>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen141
\Gin@req@width=\dimen142
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-03-30 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count193
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
)
(./Test.aux)
\openout1 = `Test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count194
\scratchdimen=\dimen143
\scratchbox=\box52
\nofMPsegments=\count195
\nofMParguments=\count196
\everyMPshowfont=\toks17
\MPscratchCnt=\count197
\MPscratchDim=\dimen144
\MPnumerator=\count198
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count199
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks18
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
!pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file ./TestFig.pdf): reading image
 file failed
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I read through the related posts and tried deleting all auxiliary files, closing any .pdf files, changing the default .pdf viewer (Preview/Acrobat), re-booting,..., but I always get the same outcome.

Comment: The main issue seems to lie with `TestFig.pdf`, which you don't provide. Here's a first stab at a resolution - convert the PDF to something else (like a jpeg, just through a screen grab) and see if that works for inclusion. This may further isolate `TestFig.pdf` as the source of the problem, not (La)TeX.

Comment: Thank you. I tried with different figures, both in .pdf and .jpg format, and I always get the same error message. I can add my TestFig.pdf into the question.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not manage to include TestFig.pdf... But I have the same problem with any .pdf or .jpg figure. Also, this problem does not arise at all on my other computer.

Comment: what happens with `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}`?

Comment: I am sorry, is the question about any figure with example-image.pdf name or are you asking about a specific figure?

Comment: @Lednacek `example-image.pdf` is an always available image to use for tests or demonstrations (e.g. ``/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.pdf``)

Comment: Ok, thank you! That does compile and generate a .pdf. This is odd.

Comment: well at least it means that your binary is not completly broken, but there is a problem either with your figure or with the folder. What happens if you copy example-image.pdf in the current folder? Does it work?

Comment: Thank you. I tried in the current folder. It did compile once, but when I closed TexShop, deleted the auxiliary files and tried again, it does not work anymore. Did not manage to make it work. Compilation works without any issues on my other computer.

Comment: It was an issue with the folder! Thank you again for your help!

Comment: What issue with the folder? I'm having the same problem